# onMessage listener not working when main.dart executes in push notifications flutter web

Tags: flutter, push-notification, web-notifications

I want to integrate push notifications in flutter. My web whole code is as:

my **index.html** code is as:

```
<html>
<title>Firebase Messaging Demo</title>
<style>
    div {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="token"></div>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <div id="notis"></div>
    <div id="err"></div>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script>
        MsgElem = document.getElementById('msg');
        TokenElem = document.getElementById('token');
        NotisElem = document.getElementById('notis');
        ErrElem = document.getElementById('err');

        // TODO: Replace firebaseConfig you get from Firebase Console
        var firebaseConfig = {
            // apiKey: ...
            // projectId: ...
            // messagingSenderId: ...
            // appId: ...
            // ...other configs...
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging
            .requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                MsgElem.innerHTML = 'Notification permission granted.';
                console.log('Notification permission granted.');

                // get the token in the form of promise
                return messaging.getToken();
            })
            .then(function (token) {
                TokenElem.innerHTML = 'Device token is : <br>' + token;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                ErrElem.innerHTML = ErrElem.innerHTML + '; ' + err;
                console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
            });

        let enableForegroundNotification = true;
        messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
            console.log('Message received. ', payload);
            NotisElem.innerHTML =
                NotisElem.innerHTML + JSON.stringify(payload);

            if (enableForegroundNotification) {
                let notification = payload.notification;
                navigator.serviceWorker
                    .getRegistrations()
                    .then((registration) => {
                        registration[0].showNotification(notification.title);
                    });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

and my **firebase-messaging-sw.js** code is as:

```
    importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts(
    "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-messaging.js",
);
// For an optimal experience using Cloud Messaging, also add the Firebase SDK for Analytics.
importScripts(
    "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js",
);

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: "YOUR-SENDER-ID",
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
    appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log(
        "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
        payload,
    );
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: "Background Message body.",
        icon: "/itwonders-web-logo.png",
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(
        notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions,
    );
});
```

This whole code is working correct and but my dart screens not showing. And if I try to run my man.dart file then notifications donot work, only main.dart works.
Please give some suggestion or idea that how can I made them both to work.

Comment: Same here, I am able to print in console (inspect element) but not able to get in main.dart.